# Cassandra Datastax driver prepared statement evaluates 'now()' once only

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm using Cassandra 1.2.4 and 1.0.0 of the Datastax java driver (through Clojure's Alia, but I don't think that matters here).  If I prepare a statement with a timeuuid column, and put 'now()' in the values for the timeuuid, now() gets evaluated once at the time the prepared statement is compiled, and then never again.

imagine this prepared statement:  "insert into some_table (id,time) values (?,now())"

after you prepare it, every time you execute it, now() will always be the same, regardless of when you execute it.

you can sort of work around this using the min/max timeuuid functions, but then you lose all the benefits of the uniqueness of timeuuid values.  effectively, I think this means that I can't insert a timeuuid using a prepared statement.

Am I missing something?  or is there a feature missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a bug/shortcoming on cassandra side. Alternatively you could pass a uuid instance as a value to the prepared statement:

insert into some_table (id,time) values (?,?)

and then use either a UUID instance you create from the UUIDs namespace http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/apidocs/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html#timeBased() in java-driver or a com.eaio.uuid.UUID instance, you can create the latter from a clojure wrapper: mpenet/tardis (it's in the dev/test dependencies of alia already), using (unique-time-uuid (java.util.Date.)).

I might just wrap uuids too on alia directly, tardis is more flexible in some ways, but the former is the official thing.

https://github.com/mpenet/tardis

I have confirmed with c* people this is something that will/can be improved, there is an issue about this here if you want to track its progress: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5616

Comment: I just did what I mentioned as Alia 1.4.0 , see http://mpenet.github.io/alia/qbits.alia.uuid.html

Comment: wrapping uuids in alia is ideal -- that also gives me access to the generated uuid in code immediately. I'm updating my alia dep to 1.4.0 and will give it a shot now. thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it works. It seems things are moving fast on CASSANDRA-5616 , this could very well be fixed in cassandra 1.2.6.